# How to give an Input to a webpage through Unix

Tags: shell, unix, curl, web

I'm needed some help regarding Unix scripting.
i have a webpages(URLs) which needs to be validated manually daily. i wanted to automate this process.

for validating we need to give a common Input on the page and hit submit it will lead you to the result page. I want to test this through Unix script . How can this be done ?

Suggestions for automation in any other language are most welcome.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: The utility is called "curl" and you would probably have better luck asking how to use it on unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at curl, it can be used in shell scripts or interactive mode: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html